# unable to instantiate a user defined class in java

Tags: java, arraylist, objectinstantiation

I am unable to instantiate a user defined class. I am writing a servant class for RMI server wherein I am trying to instantiate another class. PFB a small extract of my code

```
public void subscribe(String user, String stockSym)throws RemoteException {
    try{
           System.out.println("In the servant");
           StockUser s = new StockUser(user, stockSym);
           System.out.println("In the servant2");
           System.out.println("In the servant1");
           ......
      }
```

subscribe --> a method of my servant class

StockUser --> the user defined class that I am trying to instantiate

It is simply skipping the rest of the lines from the line `StockUser s = new StockUser(user, stockSym);`. Even with a try-catch I am unable to capture any exception. If I comment `StockUser s = new StockUser(user, stockSym);` line out then all the rest of the lines are getting executed. The variables `user`and `stockSym` are being correctly populated and are not NULL. Can someone please tell me what might be the problem?

Comment: Please show the `StockUser` constructor

Comment: public class StockUser {
    private String userName;
    private ArrayList<String> stockSym;
    private static int id = 1;
    public StockUser()
    {
       
       userName = "";
       id++;
    }
    public StockUser(String user)
    {
        userName = user;
       id++;
    }
    public StockUser(String userName, String stock)
    {
        stockSym.add(stock);
       this.userName = userName;
       id++;
    }

Comment: Any what is this mysterious exception? Or do we guess?

Comment: **Don't post updates to your question in comments. Edit your question.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stockSym.add(stock)` would give you `NullPointerException`, since you don't initialize `stockSym`.

```
public StockUser(String userName, String stock) 
{ 
    stockSym.add(stock); // exception here
    this.userName = userName;
    id++; 
}
```

You must initialize this list :

```
public StockUser(String userName, String stock) 
{ 
    stockSym = new ArrayList<String>();
    stockSym.add(stock);
    this.userName = userName;
    id++; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eran.. I had no idea that this was the case. Any idea what I can do now